# How can I call a C method from a library on my C# code?

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll, dllimport

I have a DLL (CliSiTef32I.dll) and I need to call the following methods on my C# code:

```
//The DLL can be downloaded at http://54.197.252.236/se/CliSiTef32I.dll

long ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativoEx(
   char* IPSiTef, 
   char* IdLoja,
   char* IdTerminal, 
   short Reservado, 
   char* ParametrosAdicionais
   )

long IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(
   long Funcao, 
   char* Valor, 
   char* CupomFiscal, 
   char* DataFiscal, 
   char* HoraFiscal, 
   char* Operador, 
   char* ParamAdic
   )
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How to do this depends on information you have not provided. What is the calling convention? Is it `cdecl`? And what are the `char*` parameters. Are they strings? What encoding? ANSI? ASCII? UTF-8? Are they input parameters? Or are they output? Which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

These might do the job:

```
[DllImport("CliSiTef32I.dll")]
public static extern int ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativoEx (
    byte[] IPSiTef, 
    byte[] IdLoja, 
    byte[] IdTerminal, 
    short Reservado, 
    byte[] ParametrosAdicionais)

[DllImport("CliSiTef32I.dll")]
public static extern int IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo (
    long Funcao, 
    byte[] Valor, 
    byte[] CupomFiscal, 
    byte[] DataFiscal, 
    byte[] HoraFiscal, 
    byte[] Operador, 
    byte[] ParamAdic)
```

I'm not entirely sure about the meaning of `short` though. If that's a 16 bit signed int, this will work.

Also, if the 32 bit int that you are returning is really a bool, you might declare the return value as such.

Comment: why you are using byte[] instead char[]?

Comment: @Felipe Because c# char is not 16 bit unlike c char that is 8 bit.

Comment: so, how to convert c# string to byte[]?

Comment: @Felipe Probably `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(somestring)` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx

Comment: C++ `long` is C# `int`. And very likely all the `char*` params translate simply to `string`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan C doesn't know the concept of a `bool`, but the int that is returned might be one. p/Invoke can make that interpretation. And if you declare the `char*` parameters as `string`, you have to specify `[DllImport("CliSiTef32I.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`.

Comment: C has a `bool` type. CharSet.Ansi is the default.